# how to load basic wordpress css

Tags: css

i am making a wordpress theme and i don't know why theme don't load a basic wordpress css. My site file css "style.css" is load but if i add wordpress php to theme in "inspect" on chrome i see that class from basic wordpress css was add but he doesn't has a style. for example my menu with wordpress php has a text decoration from basic tag . I hope you know what i mean.

My header :

```
<?php
/**
* The header for our theme
*
* This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything 
up until <div id="content">
*
* @link
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage StarterBootstrap
* @since 1.0
* @version 1.0
*/

 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>

<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">
<meta name="author" content="Autor">

<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php wp_title(); ?></title>

<!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Comment: Have you added the main [comment to the top of the stylesheet](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/#basic-structure)? Have you made sure that the theme is active under Appearance -> Themes? Also, I suggest checking out [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) instead of adding them statically to your `header.php`

Comment: There are no styles, just classes, the styles are up to you.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn't load any of styles on the front-end. Some WordPress functions output HTML markup with classes and IDs, but it's the job of the theme to style to this markup.

Some default styless that you'll see, such as `text-decoration` on links, are just the *browser's* default styles.